# Размеры окна программы в исходниках и при компиляции

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это обычное окно созданное при компиляции нового проекта.

Несколько вопросов:

1. Почему разный размеры окна программы в исходниках и при компиляции?
2. Возможно ли настроить VS таким образом, что было при компиляции все размеры формы совпадали с окном конструктора XAML?

Я кажется понимаю из-за чего происходит такая разница. В Windpws используется тема, которой нет в VS. Хотя могу ошибаться.

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid />
</Window>
```

Comment: @FoggyFinder, извиняюсь, что так долго не заходил. Я отредактировал вопрос. Давным-давно когда я увлекался Delphi, конструктор Delphi все строил правильно - пиксель в пиксель. А тут непонятное...

Answer (score 1):

В исходниках у вас ширина и высота клиентской области + рамок.
Но тема делает эти рамки прозрачными.
То есть, в вашем случае по 7 пикселей слева и справа не видны.

Почитайте здесь: [WPF: Нестандартное окно](https://habrahabr.ru/post/158561/)

Узнать клиентские размеры можно так:

```
var h = ((Panel)Application.Current.MainWindow.Content).ActualHeight;
var w = ((Panel)Application.Current.MainWindow.Content).ActualWidth;
```

Comment: Максим, спасибо за ответ Вы подтвердили мои догадки, что это тема. Ответьте, если знаете, на второй вопрос. Где возможно, если возможно, поменять тему и на какую, что было все 1 в 1? Или делать заголовки формы и рамки самому это единственный вариант для совпадения 1 в 1?

Comment: Не разу не менял тему в WPF приложениях, считаю что нужно придерживаться системной.

Comment: Но все равно спасибо.